# Unexpectedly const is changed to null before eval$

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8, puppeteer, browser-automation

`shelfCategoryLinks` is array of links to particular categories,
despite of use `await page.waitForSelector('.itemCount');` `itemCounter` sometimes returning null which break the app

```
 for (let shelf of shelfCategoryLinks) {
                logger.info('Processing shelf: ' + shelf.shelfName);

                //Wait some time before next operation
                await page.waitFor(400);

                //wait for submenu to appear
                await page.waitForSelector('#shelf-holder li.noChild');                    
                //Click into that submenu
                await page.click(`li[id='${shelf.shelfId}']`);
                //After click paroducts should load with also item counter which look like "Loaded 1-19 of 25 item"    
                //Wait for Item counter to appear
                await page.waitForSelector('.itemCount');
                //there we taking that item counter from DOM
                const itemCounter = await page.$('.itemCount');                    

                // Taking out total amount of items in shelf and parse to number from string
                const totalItem = await itemCounter.$eval(
                    'strong:last-child',
                    strong => parseInt(strong.innerHTML, 10)
                );
                console.log(totalItem);
            }
```

this code is walking by categories menu and it should return some number from HTML, but unexpectedly after few turns of loop  `const itemCounter` instead return that HTML element return null, because of that `page.$eval` is causes crashing of App. Why it return NULL?

Comment: You're executing `page.waitForNavigation()` and `page.click(...)` **in parallel**. Is that really what you want to do? It seems odd, if the click causes navigation, and may create a race condition. (And the race condition *may* explain why `itemCounter` isn't being found.)

Comment: It also seems odd you're not using `response` for anything.

Comment: Try turning off "headless mode" https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/tree/v1.11.0#debugging-tips maybe the page doesn't respond like you would imagine after a few interactions. It might be a timing problem, especially if AJAX is involved.

Comment: i Add
 `await page.reload();`
after every click it's solving the problem
I think problem was that DOM wasnt rerendering properly(I mean some of node just were switching with new ones) It caused that `waitForSelector` didint had to wait, so Pupeeteer were clicking in old link, or trying to click before something relly was

Answer (score 0):

i Add
 `await page.reload();`
after every click it's solving the problem
I think problem was that DOM wasnt rerendering properly(I mean some of node just were switching with new ones) It caused that `waitForSelector` didint had to wait, so Pupeeteer were clicking in old link, or trying to click before something relly was